# Consultas com Mysql sempre ocupado

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho, timeout

Tenho uma tarefa *cron* que obtém dados remotos a cada 2 minutos, via webservice, inserindo os valores obtidos em uma base de dados. Ao fim de cada dia, são mais de 50 mil registros criados.

O problema se dá quando meus clientes precisam acessar os dados obtidos durante o dia, numa aplicação PHP/Mysql que desenvolvi. Como as tarefas *cron* estão sempre rodando, visto que são dados *real-time*, o banco de dados está sempre "ocupado" e as requisições AJAX do *frontend* estão sempre dando *timeout*.

Como eu poderia resolver isto? Alguém já passou por algo similar?

---

Não detalhei porque são regras de negócios complexas. Vou tentar simplificar: a cada 10 minutos durante todo o dia, meu sistema se atualiza acessando uma dezena de endereços de um WS, cada um retornando um JSON bastante grande, que gera centenas de queryes cada um. O WS impõe um limite de acessos por segundo por questões de banda, então 2 minutos é o tempo que o sistema leva para obter todos os dados em cada ciclo. Então, tenho o MySQL inserindo registros massissamente a cada 8 minutos. Não posso mudar esta realidade.

As queryes que os clientes fazem são complexas e filtram campos de data e combinações de pelo 5 colunas da tabela, com chaves estrangeiras para outras quatro. São pesquisas reroativas de no mínino três meses de validade, logo milhares de registros são analizados.  Não posso criar views porque são dados em tempo real e perdem validade rápido. Não posso usar tabelas temporárias, cache ou similar porque não sei a combinação de campos que o cliente irá usar.

Gostaria de ouvir opiniões não sobre correção de código, mas sim sobre técnicas de acesso.

Dentre as opções, pensei em criar um segundo banco de dados espelhado para servir apenas como acesso (selects), não tendo assim o problema com as lock tables (gambiarra?). Outra opção seria tentar fazer as consultas nos arquivos json baixados, ao invés de utilizar o banco, porém o fato de eles estarem se atualizando em cada ciclo poderia haver um problema de ruptura do arquivo. Outra opção seria incrementar uma query mysql com todos os registros do ciclo e programar o cron para executá-la de 15 em 15 minutos(Será que uma query grande assim poderia trazer problemas)?

Comment: Existe um mundo de coisas que você pode melhorar, impossível saber como ajudar sem ter mais dados... Melhorar as querys das rotinas do cron, melhorar o pool, melhorar as querys do php e por aí vai... Tem que ter mais informação.

Comment: O problemas que podem estar causando isso podem ser diversos, detectá-los sabendo apenas o básico da estrutura de sua aplicação é pouco provável.
Faça alguns testes na aplicação, encontre alguns possíveis gargalos e compartilhe a informação para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado, não detalhei pela complexidade, mas pude adicionar mais informações à descrição do problema.

Answer (score 2):

Embora sem detalhes específicos, é possível entender o problema: **uma ou mais tabelas do seu banco de dados está passando a maior parte do tempo bloqueada** (*locked*).

Próxima pergunta: o que faz uma tabela ficar bloqueada?

## Muitas inserções

Uma primeira possibilidade é que há tantas inserções que ninguém mais consegue acessar a tabela.

Nesse caso, a solução poderia ser usar um tipo de tabela que aceite [inserções concorrentes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html).

Entretanto, esse dificilmente é o caso, porque deveria haver uma quantidade massiva e constante de inserções para causar *timeouts*.

50 mil registros não são muita coisa, pois dá apenas uns 35 registros por minuto, ou 70 a cada dois minutos. num servidor razoável, tal operação não deve levar mais de meio segundo.

## Transações

A segunda possibilidade é que o código que insere os dados abre uma transação que bloqueia os demais acessos ao banco.

Transações trazem segurança, garantindo consistência, porém são causa comum de problemas de desempenho, principalmente quando mal implementadas.

Imagine o seguinte pseudo-código:

```
rotina_mal_feita_que_insere_dados() {
    iniciaTransacao()
    dados = carregaDadosDoWebService()
    validaEProcessaDadosDoWebService(dados)
    foreach (dados -> dado) 
        insereNoBanco(dado)
    terminaTransacao()
}
```

Pensemos um pouco. O código acima faz todo mundo esperar pelo retorno do *web service* e o processamento dos dados. Isso é o mesmo que um gerente de um restaurante que somente permite que se anote o próximo pedido depois que o anterior já foi servido para o cliente, isto é, ele não está deixando os funcionários realizarem seus trabalhes em paralelo.

Algo um pouco melhor seria assim:

```
rotina_melhorada_que_insere_dados() {
    dados = carregaDadosDoWebService()
    validaEProcessaDadosDoWebService(dados)
    iniciaTransacao()
    foreach (dados -> dado) 
        insereNoBanco(dado)
    terminaTransacao()
}
```

No exemplo acima, continuamos a garantir a consistência do banco de dados, porém limitando bastante o escopo da transação, de forma que ela dure bem menos e não bloqueia o resto do sistema durante o acesso ao web service, que geralmente é algo demorado.

Porém, casa haja momentos em que muitos registros sejam retornados de uma só vez, talvez seja melhor ainda processar a inserção em blocos. Por exemplo:

```
rotina_otimizada_que_insere_dados() {
    dados = carregaDadosDoWebService()
    validaEProcessaDadosDoWebService(dados)
    iniciaTransacao()
    inseridos = 0
    foreach (dados -> dado) {
        insereNoBanco(dado)
        inseridos++
        if (inseridos > 100) {
            inseridos = 0
            terminaTransacao()
            iniciaTransacao()
        }
    }
    terminaTransacao()
}
```

No exemplo acima, a rotina faz o *commit* da transação a cada 100 registros inseridos e inicia uma nova transação. Isso dá chance à outras rotinas bloqueadas aguardando sua vez.

## Monitore o banco de dados

Enfim, não existe muito segredo. Você deve determinar quem está bloqueando suas tabelas.

De acordo com minhas sugestões, você pode verificar se há um grande volumes de dados chegando de uma só vez ou se há uma implementação ruim por parte da rotina que lê do web service e grava no banco.

Se o problema não for tão óbvio ou fácil de testar, a única forma certa é usar uma ferramenta para monitorar seu banco de dados e determinar o que está sendo executado no momento dos *timeouts*.

Uma possibilidade é usar o comando [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/thread-information.html) ou algumas ferramenta mais específica, como [esta](https://github.com/yoshinorim/MySlowTranCapture).

## Talvez não seja nada disso

Talvez nossos pressupostos estejam todos errados. Existe ainda a possibilidade dos *timeouts* ocorrerem simplesmente porque as consultas realizadas ao banco nas requisições AJAX sejam muito ineficientes.

Se a tabela tem muitos dados, tais consultas precisam necessariamente filtrar os dados com cláusulas `WHERE` usando índices e limitar resultados grandes a um *range* de no máximo algumas dezenas de registros.

Por outro lado, se, por acaso, sua tabela já tem alguns milhões de registros e o código está:

- Fazendo um `where` em um campo que não tem índice;
- Usando um `like` com porcentagem no início do texto (`campo like %texto%`)
- Processando um resultado com muitos registros em memória
- Realizando qualquer outra operação que cause um *table scan*, isto é, varredura da tabela inteira
- Acessando várias vezes o banco de dados ao invés de usar *joins*
- Ou qualquer coisa que deixe a consulta lenta independente das inserções

Então o problema obviamente é bem diferente.

Para determinar se isso pode estar ocorrendo, pause o agendamento por um breve período e verifique o quanto essas rotinas demoram para executar.

Você também pode executar as queries executadas diretamente no seu banco de dados e verificar o desempenho delas.

Finalmente, é importante entender que mesmo uma consulta ou escrita que leve alguns poucos segundos, isso pode causar o travamento ou bloqueio do sistema inteiro.

Imagine que uma operação no banco de dados que leva 10 segundos. É ruim, mas não parece nada absurdo se você pensar nisso isoladamente. Entretanto, imagine que você tem 10 usuários acessando o sistema num dado momento e todos acabam executando a mesma operação de alguma forma. Agora você tem uma fila onde o último usuário vai ser atendido após 100 segundos e qualquer acesso subsequente vai ter que esperar na fila também. Junte isso com aquele usuário que clica em *recarregar* novamente a cada 10 segundos e seu sistema pode levar muito tempo para se recuperar ou simplesmente travar.

#### Nota

**Se você identificar a causa do problema, por favor deixe um comentário aqui. Vai ajudar muita gente no futuro.**

Comment: Obrigado pela explanação, tópicos muito úteis. Pude adicionar mais informações ao problema, creio que tenha ficado mais claro agora.